# Proof on showing F(x,y) is continuous by $\epsilon - \delta$ definition

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

The task is as follows:

> **Given:** $$F(x,y) = \frac{xy(x^2 - y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}$$
>   **Goal:**  Prove that $F(x,y)$ is continuous everywhere on the plane

Here is my attempt so far:

**(1)** By the epsilon-delta definition, $F(x,y)$ is continuous if for any positive epsilon, there is a positive delta such that for any point $(a,b)$, we have
$d((x,y), (a,b)) < \delta ==> d(F(x,y), F(a,b)) < \epsilon$

By some manipulations with the norm, I figure that $|x-a|$ and $|y-b|$ both should be less than $\delta$, since the sum of their squares are less than the square of $\delta$

**(2)** But I'm having trouble in evaluating $|F(x,y) - F(a,b)|$

So far, what I get is the following (*)

$$\frac{xy(x^2 - y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} - \frac{ab(a^2 - b^2)}{a^2 + b^2}$$

After some expansions, I get to the point that the denominator is still $(x^2 + y^2)(a^2 + b^2)$, but I get trouble with cleaning up the numerator.

The numerator
$x^3ya^2 + x^3yb^2 - xy^3a^2 - xy^3b^2 - a^3bx^2 - a^3by^2 + ab^3x^2 + ab^3y^2$

I think that I have to clean up this mess until I get something in the nature of $(x-a)$ and $(y-b)$, so then I can use (1) to say something about $\delta$ with respect to $\epsilon$, but when I try grouping and expanding, I get nowhere close to my goal.  It turns out that I always get back to (*) after some attempts to group similar terms in the numerator

Then I try to first clean up $F(x,y)$ and $F(a,b)$ by multiplying by the conjugate of the denominator, but then I get something to the 4th exponent, and things get even worse >_<

Would someone please help me on this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but wouldn't it already suffice to show that $lim_{x->a}lim_{y->b}F(x,y)=F(a,b)$?

Comment: @cruise only if you take the limits simultaneously, rather than one after the other. For example $f(x,y)$ defined to be $1$ on the $x$ and $y$ axes and $0$ elsewhere would be continuous at the origin if you took the limits separately, but is not continuous in the usual definition.

Comment: @Cecile Must you use the epsilon-delta method everywhere? There are well known results that sums/products/compositions of continuous functions are also continuous. If you used that, all that you would have to prove by fiddly methods would be continuity at the origin (why?). It should also be noted that as the question stands, the function is not defined at the origin. But if you can show that the limit exists, then the function which takes the form given above everywhere but at $(0,0)$ and takes the value of the limit at $0$ is continuous.

Comment: @TomOldfield  I noticed that if I break the numerator into $xy(x-y)(x+y)$, then I have a product of 3 continuous functions, but I'm not sure about the last part $\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$,  I only know that it's bounded by $\frac{1}{x^2}$, which goes to 0 as x approaches 0, but is it enough to say the whole product (of 4 parts) is continuous?

Comment: @Cecile : The actual task you put in the gray box does not mention epsilons and deltas.  So I assume you don't have to use them, and I recommend not using them. The function is obviously continuous away from $(0,0)$, the only potential problem is at $(0,0)$.  In order to be continuous in the whole plane, $F(0,0)$ must be specified separately, because you can't divide by zero.  I'm assuming $F(0,0) = 0$ is given.  I would set $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$ and see what happens as $r \to 0^+$.